# What determines number of data packets before an ACK is sent? .NET Sockets on server

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

What determines how many data packets are sent by the server / received by the client before the client sends an ACK?  Is there any way to configure this either on server or client side to send more data before an ACK?  How long does a server keep sending packets if no ACK is received? Is this configurable? Does the server request ACKs or does the client just send them?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Google "tcp window size".  Don't mess with it.

Comment: Unless you know better than the people who made .net and Windows.  Which, if you're asking the question, you don't.

Comment: @cHao, questions asked and answers given build knowledge.

Comment: @Samuel: A little knowledge can be a dangerous thing.  You need to understand the fundamentals and how they apply, or in your case don't.  You could totally gimp your network connection by playing with settings without understanding why they exist and why they're set the way they are, and more importantly how you could improve them.  MS undoubtedly spent quite a bit time tweaking those settings for the common case; you'd have to have a pretty thorough knowledge of the underlying stuff in order to do better than they did.

Comment: @cHao, I think you're really over reacting to a few questions.  You also hit on an important point, that the settings are tweaked for the common case.  What about when there are specific issues in a specific case that one theory points to the ratio of data to ACK as being related? (in my case, I want to disprove this theory since I don't agree)  If a client's network admin thinks we're sending ACKs too often is it better to say we've tested adjusting the window size and it "gimped" the network or simply that we listened to some random person on the internet?  Knowledge and testing are good.

Comment: @Samuel: I'm not overreacting.  I'm just tired of people messing up their machines cause some jackass on the internet said "yeah, you can totally make stuff faster by messing with this registry stuff that's been hidden from you for damn good reason" (paraphrased, of course) and then being unable to fix it and calling me.  So my standard position is now "if you have to ask how to change important system settings, you shouldn't be messing with them."  :)

Comment: @cHao, don't worry. I won't call you. I don't have your number. I also don't think it'll be helpfull to call my client (or me?) a jackass.

Comment: @Samuel: Not you.  Not your client either.  Not even your client's network admin, though it sounds like he's talking out of his ass.  The aforementioned jackasses are the ones who basically advise you on how to change stuff that 99.99% of users shouldn't be messing with, without mentioning that you could end up screwing up everything by doing so.  That's just trolling, IMO.

Comment: On WinXP increasing the TCP receive window improved the download speed significantly for certain downloads. On Win7 I didn't see a reason for messing with TCP settings. It just worked as expected.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: From what i'm seeing, Win7 doesn't even let you set the window size anymore.  Might just be documentation i haven't seen yet, but a number of options were apparently removed in Vista and later.  [Including TcpWindowSize](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/87969-heres-why-tcpwindowsize-does-not-work-in-vista/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every byte sent over a TCP connection requires acknowledgement.  That's the rules.  The server doesn't explicitly request ACKs, because it doesn't have to -- it just expects that you'll play by the rules, and that when it sends data, you will acknowledge it.  If you don't send ACKs for more than a certain number of bytes, any of three things can happen -- the server will wait a while for an ACK (read: dead air), resend all that data that you haven't acknowledged yet (read: *more* network traffic), or if it's tried and failed to do so, it will reset the connection (read: "Connection reset by peer").

With all that said, you don't have to ACK every packet right away.  The server will send some number of bytes -- which will not be more, and will usually be less, than the client's advertised "receive window" -- before it requires an ACK.  You can wait and collect a couple of segments and ACK them all at once, if you like...or send them with the data you're sending to the server.  (ACKs with data are effectively free.)  **Windows does this already**; it waits about 200ms after it receives a segment before it sends an ACK.  If another segment comes in in that time, or Windows has data ready to send, an ACK is sent immediately that covers both segments.  The effect is that in the general case (a bunch of data coming in at once), the number of naked ACKs is cut in half.

If you really think you can do better than this, apparently there is a registry setting for `TcpAckFrequency`, which is "the number of TCP acknowledgements that will be outstanding before the delayed ACK timer is ignored" (read: before Windows immediately sends an ACK).  The default is 2.  You could increase this if you like, but you risk causing delays if it's too high.

There's also a `TcpDelAckTicks`, which specifies how long the delay is (in 100-ms "ticks").  By default it's 2.  Again, if it's too high, you can cause delays that slow your network to a crawl.

If you insist on trying it, check out `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`.  In there are a number of keys with GUID names; one corresponds to your current network connection.  (If you're on WiFi, there will be subkeys as well -- one for each network?)  You'll need to add the values in there -- they don't exist by default.

Also, take a look at http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26893a6-46c7-4b5c-b287-830216597340/TCPIP_Reg.doc.  It tells you about various options you can set.  Note that many of the value names do not currently exist in the registry!  You'll have to add them in order to set them.